# Auto rename compiled file in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, post-build-event

I use Delphi XE2 and I have a project called PGetBase. In this project, there is a module with a constant declaration. For example:

```
const
   FragH = 5;
   FragW = 4;
...
```

After compiling, the file is called PGetBase.exe. Is it possible to make the name of the build file dependent on the constants declared in the module, e.g. PGetBase_5_4.exe, by making use of a [Post-Build event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_Build_Events)?

Comment: In what cases do the constants change? How often do they change? Have you considered Build Configurations and Compiler Directives?

Comment: Write a post build event.

Comment: Certainly. Write a small console utility that will read your constants from the unit and then rename `PGetBase.exe` accordingly, and then run that small console utility in your Post-Build event.

Comment: @KenWhite This is where a good general purpose scripting la gauge comes in handy. No need to compile scripts. Simplifies maintenance hugely. My entire build process is orchestrated through Python.

Answer (score 3):

Add a project to the projectgroup which creates an executable that uses the same unit and changes the filename. Build and run that executable in the Post-Build event.

Comment: Wow! an elegant and hermeutic idea! Like it!
...but you may just forgot to re-compile the renamer. So it seems like "make renamer" should be not in the project group, but in the pre-build event for the project

Comment: @Arioch'The Better still is to remove the need to make the renamer

Comment: @Arioch I chose to build the renamer in the Post-Build event of the main project, because there is no need to recompile the renamer when a build of the main project fails.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Build knows nothing about the Pascal language and cannot parse the sources.

However you may extract "5" and "4" into some external text files.

```
const
   FragH = 
   {$I Frag_h.txt}
   ;
   FragW = 
   {$I Frag_W.txt}
   ;
```

Then make a simple program (or script: WSH, PowerShell, etc), that would be launched from post-build events.
You program would read those file and rename the Delphi-made PGetBase.exe to anything you wish.

PS. Of course one can parse the source unit to regain those constants, rather than offloading them into external storage. Comments hold the discussion pro et con.

PPS. NGLN came wit ha neat idea. Rather than parsing the file, you can just include that unit as part of your renamer project. Then you can add a pre-build event, that would compile(make) renamer and in post-buid the renamer would have those constants within itself. While calling make/dcc32 would probably be slower than just parsing the sources from inside the version-neutral pre-compiled renamer.exe, that NGLN's approach is elegant and self-contained in its own way.

Comment: I think I'd leave the source as is and script the parsing of the source file to pull out the constants.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, that is possible too. But what if you add into the program something new or complex, that would break the parser? The dumb solutions are often reliable ones :-)

Comment: When the parser breaks you fix it. In my experience that is rare.

Comment: Included response files are indeed more reliable. Analysing source code will require you to write a fully fledged Pascal lexer sooner or later.

Comment: Why would you need a full lexer to find these two definitions - with some conventions they are very easy to find with a regex. Sometimes we have to be pragmatic.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Regex is what we'd use here.

Comment: @jpfollenius, more likely sooner than later regexp will be required to support a comments (eg: `{image suffix}` for just the same pragmatic reasons.